# C# ref question again?

Tags: c#, .net

```
 class Foo
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = new Foo();
        var ff = f;

        Console.WriteLine(f.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine(ff.GetHashCode());

        FooFoo(ref f);
        BarBar(f);
    }

    private static void BarBar(Foo f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.GetHashCode());
    }

    private static void FooFoo(ref Foo f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
58225482
58225482
58225482
58225482
```

What is the difference between `FooFoo` and `BarBar`?

Comment: Instead of the Foo class, try doing it with a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No effective difference in this case.

The point of `ref` is not to pass a reference to an object, it is to pass a reference to a variable.

Consider the following change:

```
private static void BarBar(Foo f)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.GetHashCode());
    f = new Foo();
}

private static void FooFoo(ref Foo f)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.GetHashCode());
    f = new Foo();
}
```

In this case, the `FooFoo`'s change will also change the `f` variable in the `Main` method, but the `BarBar` method is only changing a local variable.

All reference types are passed as reference types in any case, you cannot change that. The only point to `ref` is to allow the called method to change the variable it is being passed.